# How can I change a value only if it happens between two characters in R?

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to read a csv file in R. 
The terrible people that sent me the file, included column names that contain commas. Fortunately these comma including names are always kept between brackets [].

I am pretty sure there is a similar question in Stack, but, I haven't been able to find it.
What regular expression should I use to get rid of these commas?

The string of names is like `namestring` below and I would like to obtain something like `outstring` (either with _ or any other symbol).

```
namestring="V1,V2,V3[1,5m/s2],V4,V5,V6[12,23mm]"
outstring="V1,V2,V3[1_5m/s2],V4,,V6[12_23mm]"
```

Comment: Is there a possibility of other kinds of escaping or nesting happening? Is there always a maximum of 1 comma in a name or can there be more?

Comment: In my particular case there can only be one comma. If there were more than one, I think I would execute the solution provided by akrun until the amount of commas doesn't reduce as the strings I have to parse are not too long. In any case I'm far from being an expert in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we want to remove the `,` inside the brackets,

```
gsub("\\[([^,]*),", "[\\1_", namestring)
#[1] "V1,V2,V3[1_5m/s2],V4,V5,V6[12_23mm]"
```

Comment: What if there is a square bracket that does not contain a comma?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does exactly what I need. @G5W, if no commas are included the brackets stay the same. I.E. gsub("\\[([^,]*),", "[\\1_", "[][,]")

Comment: What about multiple commas? `gsub('(?:\\G(?!^)|[^[]*\\[)[^],]*\\K,', '_', x, perl=TRUE)`